# Difficult MySQL query (MySQL-8, Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got a really difficult task for me, and I'm out of ideas. I use mysql-8, Laravel 8.

This is a structure of the tables:

- `user` has many `projects` (every project has `user_id` field)
- `project` has many `selections` (every selection has `project_id` field)
- `selection` has one `pump` (selection has `pump_id` field), but it also has `pumps_count` field
- `pump` has many `price_lists` (every price_list has `pump_id` field)
- `price_list` and `user` also have `country_id`, `currency_id`, so we can say that `pump` has ONE `price_list` that corresponds to current user. (For example if current `user` has `country_id` = 1 and `currency_id` = 2 then we should select only price lists, where `country_id` = 1 and `currency_id` = 2 and there'll be only one)
- `projects` and `selections` both have `created_at` field (timestamp).

So, the main goals:

1. For current user get total price of projects, grouped by months
2. For current user get total price of projects with 'increasing' grouped by months

users

| id | country_id | currency_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

projects

| id | created_at | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 00:00:01 | proj1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 00:00:01 | proj2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-12-01 00:00:01 | proj3 | 1 |

selections

| id | created_at | project_id | pump_id | pumps_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 00:00:01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-11-03 00:00:01 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-04 00:00:01 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2021-12-05 00:00:01 | 3 | 1 | 3 |

pumps

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

pumps_price_lists

| pump_id | country_id | currency_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 500 |

Result for the first part:

| year-month | total_projects_price |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10 | 200 |
| 2021-11 | 800 |
| 2021-12 | 300 |

Result for the second part:

| year-month | total_projects_price_with_increasing |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10 | 200 |
| 2021-11 | 1000 |
| 2021-12 | 1300 |

Total price for project = total price of selections of the project.

Total price of selection = total pumps price of the selection.

Total pumps price of the selection = `selection.pumps_count` * pump price.

Pump price = `pumps_price_lists.price` for pump where `county_id` and `currency_id` are the same as user has.

I'm looking at this and really don't know where to even start. Project becomes quite big, so I would want the solution to not has `join`s, but any ideas are welcome.

I tried something like this with joins, but it doesn't seem work:

```sql
select
    selections.id as 'selection_id', 
    DATE_FORMAT(selections.created_at, '%Y-%m') as 'month',
    pumps_price_lists.price,
    pumps_price_lists.currency_id as 'currency_id',
    sum(pumps_price_lists.price) over (ORDER by DATE_FORMAT(selections.created_at, '%Y-%m')) as 'sum'
from projects
join selections on selections.project_id = projects.id
join pumps on selections.pump_id = pumps.id
join pumps_price_lists on pumps_price_lists.pump_id = pumps.id
GROUP BY selections.id, pumps_price_lists.currency_id
```

I also tried to do something with Laravel Eloquent, but stucked and don't know what to do next.

```php
Auth::user()->projects()
    ->with(['selections' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'pumps_count', 'pump_id', 'created_at', 'project_id');
    }, 'selections.pump' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id');
    }, 'selections.pump.price_list', 'selections.pump.price_list.currency'
    ])->get(['id', 'created_at', 'user_id'])->...
```

I hope my explanation was clear

Comment: Can you add your example tables to a DB fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: I think by "with increasing" you mean "cumulative"?

Comment: @lufc yes, you're right - cumulative. Table are [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1vqoCCjkhaJLJaqpqorC9/1). I hope I did it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL I would do it something like

```
with data as 
(select
DATE_FORMAT(selections.created_at, '%Y-%m') as m,
sum(price * pumps_count) as total_price
from users
left join projects on (projects.user_id = users.id)
left join selections on (selections.project_id = projects.id)
left join pumps_price_lists on (pumps_price_lists.pump_id = selections.pump_id)
where users.id = 1
group by m
)

select *, sum(total_price) over (order by m) as cumulative_price from data
```